# How do I go about setting up a service from a console application?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I never setup a service from a console app so any info would be quite helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that you have an existing console app with the funcionality and now want to make a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean a Windows service. You may want to check out (and use) the excellent TopShelf library: http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/index.html. It can be used to easily host your app components as a service, and supports various install/uninstall and hosting scenarios. Also there is a lot of documentation and examples on its usage available.

Comment: Thanks for the Documentation! I'm just trying to implement a program into a windows service.